# Can we merge [gles] with [opengl-es]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [gles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gles) only has one question and it's actually about [opengl-es](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opengl-es) can we make [gles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gles) a synonym of [opengl-es](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opengl-es) and merge them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the tag only has one usage and it's going to be destroyed soon, I move for replacing it and merging the tags. I believe this is just the obvious choice here, but other inputs are welcome.

Comment: This has been done.